# How to include double quotes in a value when using "put" command via GFSH

Tags: geode, gfsh

An example of put command that I have been using:

```
put --key=('Foo123') --value=('id':'123') --region=/region1
```

And if I were to include spaces in the value:

```
put --key=('Foo123') --value="('id':'123 456')" --region=/region1
```

But am unable to include double quotes in the value. e.g.

```
put --key=('Foo123') --value="('id':'123 "xxx" 456')" --region=/region1
```

Tried to escape the double quotes but not working:

```
put --key=('Foo123') --value="('id':'123 \"0\" 456')" --region=/region1
```